# How can I expand images on hover with canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, canvas, d3.js

I really like in this example http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/09/13/fashion-week-editors-picks/ how the images expand on hover. I know how I could do this with jquery but I also know it wouldn't be as fast and reliable. I could give it a try with d3js but I am really new to it, any idea where I could start or other viable alternatives?

thanks

Comment: Probably the responsiveness of the NYT example comes from using a single canvas (or small number of them) instead of a bunch of HTML or SVG nodes —— not from using d3 instead of jQuery. That example does happen to use d3 though. You can see all the code by viewing source; it's right there in un-minified js. For example, line `897` of the page source is part of a big loop where it draws the current image into the canvas.

Comment: you are right!! you should have posted this as an answer! here is a fiddle with this great work they have done http://jsfiddle.net/6mohu2vk/  Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Just curious: you were able to put together that jsFiddle just by copy/pasting the js and including d3? No other dependencies?

Comment: nothing else, all it asks for is d3 and images

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
<div style = "display:inline;" id = "imgBar">
</div>
```

css:

```
#imgBar{
//CSS here
}

#imgBar > img:hover{
width:200px; //Just set the width to double it's default value
height:200px; //Same as above; 200px is just a dummy value
}
```

Then, you can add images to the div with javascript.

---

## Good Luck!